# imagenes svg en fpdf

Tags: fpdf, svg

me han pasado un código de una aplicación donde una de sus funciones es la generación de un pdf. Para ello usa lo siguiente **from fpdf import FPDF**. En el momento de su programación se que daba error con imágenes svg. ¿la librería que se emplea ya se ha actualizado y permite cargar las templeates como sgv o tengo que buscar otras opciones?
Gracias de antemano.